# Is it possible to remobe _afpovertcp._tcp.local from ser name?

Tags: macos, network, nas, afp

I'm connecting to a WD MyCloud NAS over my local network.
When I connect using the IP I get a clean address like afp://192.168.0.20/folder/file, which is nice, but when I connect using the server name, I get this weird ugly afp://Server._afpovertcp._tcp.local/folder/file.

Is there a way to have it just as afp://server/folder/file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding the server name and IP to your host files in Mac? I would recommend having a static IP on your NAS for this.

1. Launch Terminal, type `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` and press Return.
2. You’ll need to also enter your admin password to execute it, as with all sudo commands.
3. You will now have the hosts file open in the Nano editor. Use the arrow keys on your keyboard, to navigate and edit the file.
4. In your case it can be:

   ```
   192.168.0.20         Server(type any name that you prefer)
   ```
5. Like with the Windows method above you should just add the desired IP followed by the hostname (or domain name) at the bottom after `::1 localhost`.
6. Press **Control-O** to save the file.
7. Flush the cache from the terminal with `dscacheutil -flushcache`
8. Test with the name that you have put.

Comment: Yeah, this is the static IP of my NAS already. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.